# Vscode gives error "could not import fmt (cannot find package "fmt" )" for simple go program

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Following is my system configuration.

OS : Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise

Go version: go version go1.15.7 windows/amd64

The program which I am trying to execute is as below

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World from Go")
}
```

The problem is I can compile and run a simple Hello world program from the command line but inside vscode it showed the error.

```
could not import fmt (cannot find package "fmt" in any of   c:\go\src\fmt (from $GOROOT)
    C:\Users\ameena\go\src\fmt (from $GOPATH))compiler
```

Am I missing here something ??

Regards
Amit

Comment: Also note that your Go version is outdated and no longer supported.

Comment: Thanks @Volker I will update that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [explained here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/configuring-goroot-and-gopath.html) (for GoLand, but it applies to VSCode-Go as well)

> `GOROOT` is a variable that defines where your Go SDK is located.
> You do not need to change this variable, unless you plan to use different Go versions.
>
> `GOPATH` is a variable that defines the root of your workspace.
> By default, the workspace directory is a directory that is named `go` within your user home directory (`~/go` for Linux and MacOS, `%USERPROFILE%/go` for Windows).

If you did not install Go in the default paths (`C:\Go`), you need to set the `GOROOT` environment variable to the root folder of your Go installation.

The [OP Amit Meena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5659521/amit-meena) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69939306/for-simple-go-program-vscode-gives-error-could-not-import-fmt-cannot-find-packa/69939504?noredirect=1#comment123632429_69939504):

> Seems in my env `GOROOT` variable was missing: on creating the `GOROOT` variable and pointing it to go installation directory, the error has gone from VSCode.

Comment: let me check this setting

Comment: @AmitMeena In other words, where did you install Go on your machine?

Comment: My go installation path is : C:\Go

Comment: And my GOPTH varaible is configured as  %USERPROFILE%\go

Comment: @AmitMeena That seems good. Is there any chance VSCode is launched from a different account, with no rights to read those folders? Or with its VSCode settings set to a different path for Go?

Comment: Seems in my env GOROOT variable was missing, on creating the GOROOT variable and pointing it to go installation directory the error has gone from vscode

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Vonc for the quickest response :)

Comment: @AmitMeena Well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.